# Embed a browser in Flex

Tags: php, html, apache-flex, rss, ria

Anyone know of any documentation that would help me with trying to embed a web browser component into adobe flex.

I've seen in Adobe Air that there is a   Item; however, in Adobe Flex 3 for a .swf file that would be somewhere - I do not see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, you're deploying your flex app into a browser environment, why can't you just utilize that? Rather than trying to embed a browser in an app in a browser.

Comment: Well, I know I could just embed the SWF into the browser...but I'm curious to see if it's something that can be done.

It's a small project I'm messing with at home just to learn more about Flex and what not - kind of re-inventing the wheel to learn about the wheel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only Air has that capability built in.

However there is a very good-looking component that you can find here:
http://drumbeatinsight.com/

It is paid-for though.

Open source solutions are here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/as3htmlparser/
and here:
http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/

Answer (score 2):

The Webkit engine is embedded in the AIR runtime. It is not embedded in the Flash plug-in, however, so you cannot embed a browser within a .swf (Flash application) running inside a Web browser (or even using a standalone, desktop .swf runtime) as the Flash plug-in doesn't support that. AIR is your only option for actually embedding a browser within a Flash application.

There are a number of examples on the Web of using s to position a browser component/window over a Flash application to make it look like you've embedded a browser inside of the Flash app. Before AIR came along, this was what a lot of Flash/Flex developers did.