# Trying to show a PDF page inside a SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, pdf, movieclip

I want to "embed" a SWF into a Flash (not Flex or Flash Builder) project I'm making. What I would like to do is have a page of the PDF show (inside a MovieClip) and have the rest of it available to download (probably using navigateToURL).

I've heard that this is possible by embedding it as an HTML page inside the MovieClip, though I haven't found any info about it. Worst comes to worst I could just have a JPG preview of the PDF and have it downloadable, but is there any other known way I could do it using AS3?

Comment: according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1246142/501196) only Air is capable of hosting a browser window.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the HTML component is only possible in AIR applications.

However, you can use [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org/) to convert the pdf into a swf file (each page separate or each page as 1 slide) and display this swf. The swf is zoomable without pixelating, unlike a jpg.